# Does React make a clone of your object when you use the set function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, lodash

I'm trying to avoid modifying state directly, so I am using lodash `cloneDeep()` and then setting state using the clone. However, I want to make additional changes (after an async request) and set state again. After I and pass my clone to the set function, is it off limits to continue making changes to that clone? Do I need to re-clone my clone to be safe, or does React make a clone of my clone? The code may help explain the issue:

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState({ name: '', email: '' })

const newUser = cloneDeep(user) // cloning to avoid modifying state directly
newUser.name = 'Steve' // setting a property on the clone
setUser(newUser) // all good up to this point

// some async stuff happens, then later:

newUser.email = 'steve@example.com' // still modifying the clone, but is this safe?
setUser(newUser)
```

Since I modified the clone that I previously passed with setUser did that just modify state directly?

I tried to inspect the React source code to determine if they were making a clone when I called `setUser()` but I couldn't comprehend what was going on. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newUser.email = 'steve@example.com' // still modifying the clone, but is this safe?
setUser(newUser)
```

I don't think this is a good idea. `newUser` is the same reference that you used in the previous call to `setUser` (before async request), so react may actually [bail](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update) out of this `setState` because it is same as the value which you used during previous call to `setState`.

Also your situation is same as this

```
let user = {};
setUser(user);
user.a=1;
```

in the following sense: once I pass `user` to `setUser` on step 2, it doesn't matter whether it is brand new object or something that I cloned before, *the point is on step 3 I am modifying something I passed to `setUser` in step 2*. And this does look to me like modifying something which is in state.

---

So try to update state in *immutable* way the second time too. Most of the time doing immutable state updates with shallow copy using `...` has worked for me (if you do it right), so you could avoid extra library.

Comment: Thank you! This made a lot of sense and I am now just using nested spread operators to avoid having to create multiple clones. I was indeed running into an issue where it wouldn't re-render and now I understand that it was due to the bail feature you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify this:

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState({ name: '', email: '' })

// spread and create a new object
// and append the new property  
const newUser = { …user, name: “Steve” }

setUser(newUser)

// Async call happens

// spread and create a new object
// and append the new property
setUser({ …newUser, email: “steve@example.com” })
```

All it takes is using the spread operator.

I am not sure what the reasons are for setting name first and then the emsil, but why not make the call first and setUser altogether? You won’t have to worry about any of the above that way. It’ll save a render cycle too.

Comment: Thank you, this was a contrived example, in the real function I am doing some validation that requires a call to the server, then setting other properties, so it makes sense, but I tried to simplify the code for this example. Also, my reason for using `cloneDeep()` is that in my real function I have a big nested object. Regardless, I am now just doing nested spreads.